# how do I make gnuplot plot in a gui interface instead of inside of a terminal?

Tags: terminal, plot, cygwin, gnuplot, octave

How do I change the plot function in ocatave to get the plots in a new gui interface..

I used to get the graphs in a white gui window and was able to see colors etc, but now in a different computer I'm getting graphs inside the terminal window as shown in the figure..[image: gnuplot]

I installed octave and gnuplot from cygwin..
what are the additional cygwin pacakages I need to install or what are the settings I need to change in gnuplot/octave?

Comment: you must had a problem when installing it. That's gnuplot you're seeing and it defaults to ASCII plots if the X display is not configured.

Comment: You should check to see if you have `x11` installed.  If not, you'll need to install it and probably re-install gnuplot.  As a side note, this is the first time I've ever seen the ascii terminal in action.